# Textbox Auto Complete - Winform + LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, algorithm

I'm building a simple win form application with one dataGrid, one TextBox.
I have about 10K records of names.

What I want to do is implement some sort of auto complete feature so when a user types into the textbox, the datagrid is updated to display the matches accordingly.

Just to test this out, I have one DataContext object that returns the names table and I put some code in the textBox1_TextChanged event to reset the data source with

`this.dataGrid1.DataSource = (from p in connectionWrapper.getConnectionObj.PatientsNormalizeds
                                             where p.Name.Contains(textBox1.Text)
                                             select p).Take(30);`

This works fine over local connection but when pulling data off a remote SQL server this is of course too slow, typing becomes sluggish and is unacceptable for users.

Just wondering if anything can be done with out changing the design. I can of course load the entire table into an list or DataTable at form_loading and run search against it but that will cause the form to stop responding for 3 seconds or so...

This is probably very simple for most developers but I'm very new.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you first select ALL names containing the user input in the DB, and only after that, you take the first 30 results. But your DB has been totally processed ! You should stop your query right after the 30 first results have been found. I don't know LINQ or SQL well enough to answer, but the solution should be easy if you do.

Comment: is p a string or is it populating an object? Sometimes if your returning a number of objects it will significantly slow down your load time because it has to populate each object.

Comment: It is an object but nothing fancy, just name, dob, phone# etc etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of approaches spring to mind. The first would involve not filtering on every key press but rather searching when the user has paused, i.e. they think they've typed enough and want to see what that returns. This could be done using a timer where the delay is reset with every key press.

Using a background thread to run the query leaves the interface responsive while the data is retrieved.

I'd also look at returning the minimum object from the LINQ, i.e. just p.Name rather than the whole p object. That will also help speed the data transmission and responsiveness.

Comment: This can be easily implemented by using Reactive Extensions.

Comment: @Giorgi, that looks like an answer. You should post it as such.

Comment: I've just posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reactive Extensions to easily implement a solution which queries remote server if user has typed certain amount of symbols, paused for some time, very easily. The following hands on lab does exactly this: [Rx .NET HOL](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/5/D/C5D669F9-01DF-4FAF-BBA9-29C096C462DB/Rx%20HOL%20.NET.pdf)

Comment: I took the easy way out by changing my design to fetch when paused and using a backgroundworker, now the delay is not apparent to the user.

Comment: Would using Rx give better performance? or is this more a design - oriented improvement.

Comment: @Rillanon - I don't think it will give better performance as it does not really matter what fetches data from sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the select on a background thread aka `BackgroundWorker`

Answer (score 0):

You can cache data locally in XML file or something. Application may be unresponsive for the first time (unless you're preloading data in background using threads), but it will be really fast for every other time you run the application.
You can implement a preloading/splash screen to notify users that data are loaded in the background.